# Powerpivot: how do I avoid measures from computing until I'm done entering multiple measures?

Tags: microsoft-excel, powerpivot, usability

With Powerpivot, I have many measures (>25) to enter in a dataset that has millions of entries. When entering the DAX expressions for the measures, each time I enter one, Powerpivot takes a long time to calculate that value before it allows me to enter the next one.

Is there a way to tell Powerpivot to temporarily not perform any computations, so I can enter all my DAX expressions, and then have it calculate them all together when I'm done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 2013 there is an addin you can download that lets you disable refreshes.
https://olappivottableextend.codeplex.com